# Scala: Draw table to console

Tags: scala, console-application, rendering, tabular

I need to display a table in a console.

My simple solution, if you would call it a "solution", is as follows:

```
  override def toString() = {
    var res = "\n"
      var counter = 1;
      res += stateDb._1 + "\n"
      res += "  +----------------------------+\n"
      res += "  +     State Table            +\n"
      res += "  +----------------------------+\n"
      for (entry <- stateDb._2) {
        res += "  | " + counter + "\t | " + entry._1 + " | " + entry._2 + " |\n"
        counter += 1;
      }
      res += "  +----------------------------+\n"
      res += "\n"
    res

  }
```

We don't have to argue this

- a is looking bad when displayed
- b code looks kinda messed up

Actually, such a question was asked for C# but I would like to know a nice solution for Scala as well.

So what is a (nice/good/simple/whatever) way to draw such a table in Scala to the console?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Column 1     |    Column 2     |    Column 3     |    Column 4     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
|                 |                 |                 |                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I've pulled the following from my current project:

```
object Tabulator {
  def format(table: Seq[Seq[Any]]) = table match {
    case Seq() => ""
    case _ => 
      val sizes = for (row <- table) yield (for (cell <- row) yield if (cell == null) 0 else cell.toString.length)
      val colSizes = for (col <- sizes.transpose) yield col.max
      val rows = for (row <- table) yield formatRow(row, colSizes)
      formatRows(rowSeparator(colSizes), rows)
  }

  def formatRows(rowSeparator: String, rows: Seq[String]): String = (
    rowSeparator :: 
    rows.head :: 
    rowSeparator :: 
    rows.tail.toList ::: 
    rowSeparator :: 
    List()).mkString("\n")

  def formatRow(row: Seq[Any], colSizes: Seq[Int]) = {
    val cells = (for ((item, size) <- row.zip(colSizes)) yield if (size == 0) "" else ("%" + size + "s").format(item))
    cells.mkString("|", "|", "|")
  }

  def rowSeparator(colSizes: Seq[Int]) = colSizes map { "-" * _ } mkString("+", "+", "+")
}

scala> Tabulator.format(List(List("head1", "head2", "head3"), List("one", "two", "three"), List("four", "five", "six")))
res1: java.lang.String = 
+-----+-----+-----+
|head1|head2|head3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|  one|  two|three|
| four| five|  six|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: this is beautiful. Tried it and was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: as an addition this is left alignement ("%" + size + "s").format(item) this right ("%-" + size + "s").format(item)

Comment: Would be even nicer as an `implicit class` that adds e.g. `.asTable` to e.g. `Seq[Seq[Any]]` :)

Comment: This is neat, thanks.

Using console colours seems to mess up the spacing though, any idea why?

Comment: Oh never mind, I think it's because of special characters used to display the color is counted towards maximum column's size.

Comment: @evildead: Isn't it the other way around? ("%-" + size + "s").format(item) is for left alignment? Anyway, thanks! That comment helped a lot to adapt the code above to my problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you want it somewhat more compact. Bonus: left aligned and padded with 1 char on both sides. Based on the answer by Duncan McGregor (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542476/8547501):

```
def formatTable(table: Seq[Seq[Any]]): String = {
  if (table.isEmpty) ""
  else {
    // Get column widths based on the maximum cell width in each column (+2 for a one character padding on each side)
    val colWidths = table.transpose.map(_.map(cell => if (cell == null) 0 else cell.toString.length).max + 2)
    // Format each row
    val rows = table.map(_.zip(colWidths).map { case (item, size) => (" %-" + (size - 1) + "s").format(item) }
      .mkString("|", "|", "|"))
    // Formatted separator row, used to separate the header and draw table borders
    val separator = colWidths.map("-" * _).mkString("+", "+", "+")
    // Put the table together and return
    (separator +: rows.head +: separator +: rows.tail :+ separator).mkString("\n")
  }
}

scala> formatTable(Seq(Seq("head1", "head2", "head3"), Seq("one", "two", "three"), Seq("four", "five", "six")))
res0: String =
+-------+-------+-------+
| head1 | head2 | head3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| one   | two   | three |
| four  | five  | six   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Ton of thanks for the Tabulator code!

There is a modification for **Spark** dataset tabular printing.

I mean you can print DataFrame content or pulled result set, like

```
Tabulator(hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM stat"))
Tabulator(hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM stat").take(20))
```

The second one will be without header of course, for DF implementation you can set how many rows to pull from Spark data frame for printing and do you need header or not.

```
 /**
 * Tabular representation of Spark dataset.
 * Usage:
 * 1. Import source to spark-shell:
 *   spark-shell.cmd --master local[2] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0 -i /path/to/Tabulator.scala
 * 2. Tabulator usage:
 *   import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
 *   val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
 *   val stat = hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").load("D:\\data\\stats-belablotski.tsv")
 *   stat.registerTempTable("stat")
 *   Tabulator(hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM stat").take(20))
 *   Tabulator(hiveContext.sql("SELECT * FROM stat"))
 */
object Tabulator {

  def format(table: Seq[Seq[Any]], isHeaderNeeded: Boolean) : String = table match {
    case Seq() => ""
    case _ => 
      val sizes = for (row <- table) yield (for (cell <- row) yield if (cell == null) 0 else cell.toString.length)
      val colSizes = for (col <- sizes.transpose) yield col.max
      val rows = for (row <- table) yield formatRow(row, colSizes)
      formatRows(rowSeparator(colSizes), rows, isHeaderNeeded)
  }

  def formatRes(table: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]): String = {
    val res: Seq[Seq[Any]] = (for { r <- table } yield r.toSeq).toSeq
    format(res, false)
  }

  def formatDf(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, n: Int = 20, isHeaderNeeded: Boolean = true): String = {
    val res: Seq[Seq[Any]] = (for { r <- df.take(n) } yield r.toSeq).toSeq
    format(List(df.schema.map(_.name).toSeq) ++ res, isHeaderNeeded)
  }

  def apply(table: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]): Unit = 
    println(formatRes(table))

  /**
   * Print DataFrame in a formatted manner.
   * @param df Data frame
   * @param n How many row to take for tabular printing
   */
  def apply(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, n: Int = 20, isHeaderNeeded: Boolean = true): Unit =
    println(formatDf(df, n, isHeaderNeeded))

  def formatRows(rowSeparator: String, rows: Seq[String], isHeaderNeeded: Boolean): String = (
    rowSeparator :: 
    (rows.head + { if (isHeaderNeeded) "\n" + rowSeparator else "" }) :: 
    rows.tail.toList ::: 
    rowSeparator :: 
    List()).mkString("\n")

  def formatRow(row: Seq[Any], colSizes: Seq[Int]) = {
    val cells = (for ((item, size) <- row.zip(colSizes)) yield if (size == 0) "" else ("%" + size + "s").format(item))
    cells.mkString("|", "|", "|")
  }

  def rowSeparator(colSizes: Seq[Int]) = colSizes map { "-" * _ } mkString("+", "+", "+")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tokenize it.  I'd start with looking at making a few case objects and classes so that you produce a tokenized list which can be operated on for display purposes:

```
sealed trait TableTokens{
  val width: Int
}
case class Entry(value: String) extends TableTokens{
  val width = value.length
}
case object LineBreak extends TableTokens{
  val width = 0
}
case object Div extends TableTokens{
  val width = 1
}
```

So then you can form certain constraints with some sort of row object:

```
case class Row(contents: List[TableTokens]) extends TableTokens{
  val width = contents.foldLeft(0)((x,y) => x = y.width)
}
```

Then you can check for constraits and things like that in an immutable fashion.  Perhaps creating methods for appending tables and alignment...

```
case class Table(contents: List[TableTokens])
```

That means you could have several different variants of tables where your style is different from your structure, a la HTML and CSS.

Comment: maybe you can add a little example. I'm not getting it fully.

Comment: I second @evildead—why tokenize anything if this is about rendering an existing sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some modifications of @Duncan McGregor answer to accept unicode's box drawing or custom characters using Scala 3.

First we define a class to host the custom separators:

```
  type ColumnSep = (Char, Char, Char)

  case class TableSeparator(horizontal: Char, vertical: Char, upLeft: Char, upMiddle: Char, upRight: Char, middleLeft: Char, middleMiddle: Char, middleRight: Char, downLeft: Char, downMiddle: Char, downRight: Char):

    def separate(sep: TableSeparator => ColumnSep)(seq: Seq[Any]): String =
      val (a, b, c) = sep(this)
      seq.mkString(a.toString, b.toString, c.toString)

    def separateRows(posicao: TableSeparator => ColumnSep)(colSizes: Seq[Int]): String =
      separate(posicao)(colSizes.map(horizontal.toString * _))

    def up: ColumnSep = (upLeft, upMiddle, upRight)

    def middle: ColumnSep = (middleLeft, middleMiddle, middleRight)

    def down: ColumnSep = (downLeft, downMiddle, downRight)

    def verticals: ColumnSep = (vertical, vertical, vertical)
```

then we define the separators on the companion object

```
object TableSeparator:

  lazy val simple = TableSeparator(
    '-', '|',
    '+', '+', '+',
    '+', '+', '+',
    '+', '+', '+'
  )

  lazy val light = TableSeparator(
    '─', '│',
    '┌', '┬', '┐',
    '├', '┼', '┤',
    '└', '┴', '┘'
  )

  lazy val heavy = TableSeparator(
    '━', '┃',
    '┏', '┳', '┓',
    '┣', '╋', '┫',
    '┗', '┻', '┛'
  )

  lazy val dottedLight = TableSeparator(
    '┄', '┆',
    '┌', '┬', '┐',
    '├', '┼', '┤',
    '└', '┴', '┘'
  )

  lazy val dottedHeavy = TableSeparator(
    '┅', '┇',
    '┏', '┳', '┓',
    '┣', '╋', '┫',
    '┗', '┻', '┛'
  )

  lazy val double = TableSeparator(
    '═', '║',
    '╔', '╦', '╗',
    '╠', '╬', '╣',
    '╚', '╩', '╝'
  )
```

And finally the Tabulator:

```
  class Tabulator(val separators: TableSeparator):
    def format(table: Seq[Seq[Any]]): String = table match
      case Seq() => ""
      case _ =>
        val sizes = for (row <- table) yield for (cell <- row) yield if cell == null then 0 else cell.toString.length
        val colSizes = for (col <- sizes.transpose) yield col.max
        val rows = for (row <- table) yield formatRow(row, colSizes)
        formatRows(colSizes, rows)

    private def centralize(text: String, width: Int): String =
      val space: Int = width - text.length
      val prefix: Int = space / 2
      val suffix: Int = (space + 1) / 2
      if width > text.length then " ".repeat(prefix) + text + " ".repeat(suffix) else text  

    def formatRows(colSizes: Seq[Int], rows: Seq[String]): String =
      (separators.separateRows(_.up)(colSizes) ::
        rows.head ::
        separators.separateRows(_.middle)(colSizes) ::
        rows.tail.toList ::
        separators.separateRows(_.down)(colSizes) ::
        List()).mkString("\n")

    def formatRow(row: Seq[Any], colSizes: Seq[Int]): String =
      val cells = for (item, size) <- row zip colSizes yield if size == 0 then "" else centralize(item.toString, size)
      separators.separate(_.verticals)(cells)
```

Some output examples:

```
+---+-----+----+
| a |  b  | c  |
+---+-----+----+
|abc|true |242 |
|xyz|false|1231|
|ijk|true |312 |
+---+-----+----+
┌───┬─────┬────┐
│ a │  b  │ c  │
├───┼─────┼────┤
│abc│true │242 │
│xyz│false│1231│
│ijk│true │312 │
└───┴─────┴────┘
┏━━━┳━━━━━┳━━━━┓
┃ a ┃  b  ┃ c  ┃
┣━━━╋━━━━━╋━━━━┫
┃abc┃true ┃242 ┃
┃xyz┃false┃1231┃
┃ijk┃true ┃312 ┃
┗━━━┻━━━━━┻━━━━┛
╔═══╦═════╦════╗
║ a ║  b  ║ c  ║
╠═══╬═════╬════╣
║abc║true ║242 ║
║xyz║false║1231║
║ijk║true ║312 ║
╚═══╩═════╩════╝
```